# SQL WorkbenchTable Creation

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am making tables in SQL Workbench. I am assuming that in SQL Workbench when a table is created it contains `updated_at` and `created_at` columns by default.   Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. Well if u can answer it too it could help me alot. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work bench does not provide the created_at and updated_at columns by itself. But the MySQL as a database provides it. You can even disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether such columns would be there by default or not. 
You should check the settings. You can always check your table status by using below suggested queries:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM myDatabase LIKE 'myTable';

DESCRIBE myDatabase.myTable;
```

This link might help you:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-columns-tab.html

Delete a column that you don't want by hovering the pointer over a table > right click > alter table and then make desired changes.